# Is $\bigg\lvert\frac{1 - \zeta^s }{ 1 - \zeta}\bigg\rvert \in\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)$ for $s = 1, \ldots, p-1$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-numbers, cyclotomic-fields

> Let $p$ be an odd prime and let $\zeta$ be a $p$-th root of unity. Is it true that $$\Bigg\lvert\frac{1 - \zeta^s }{ 1 - \zeta}\Bigg\rvert \in\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)$$ for $s = 1, \ldots, p-1$?
>
> Remark: By $\lvert \cdot \rvert$ I mean the standard norm over $\mathbb{C}$.

I do not know how to prove this. I was trying to use the definition of the norm, so

\begin{align*}
\lvert 1-\zeta \rvert &= \sqrt{(1-\Re(\zeta))^2+\Im(\zeta)^2}, \\
\lvert 1-\zeta^s \rvert &= \sqrt{(1-\Re(\zeta^s))^2+\Im(\zeta^s)^2},
\end{align*}

but I do not see what to do now. I know Kummer's Lemma, but I am not sure whether it could be of use here.

Comment: what's stopping you from computing real and imaginary parts of a very simple complex number $e^{2\pi i/p} ?$

Comment: @dezdichado How does it help us to know that the number $\zeta = \exp(2\pi i/p)$  is $\cos(2\pi i/p) +i\sin (2\pi i/p)$? We can of course isolate the real and complex parts (instead of really computing them), and the hint to do so would be less offensive then the question about "what is stopping us from doing so?". Now that we have the real and imaginary part, we can plug them in - i suppose - in the expressions under the square roots. And now which is the next step? How to extract the square root, and get again an expression in the same $\sin$ and $\cos$ values?! How to get a quick end?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $z$ be the complex number
$$
z=\frac{1-\zeta^s}{1-\zeta}\ .
$$
Then the complex conjugate of $z$ is
$$
\bar z=\frac{\overline{1-\zeta^s}}{\overline{1-\zeta}}
=\frac{1-\zeta^{-s}}{1-\zeta^{-1}}
=\frac{\zeta^{-s}}{\zeta^{-1}}\cdot\frac{1-\zeta^s}{1-\zeta}
=\zeta^{1-s}\cdot z=\zeta^{2t}\cdot z
\ ,
$$
where $t$ is chosen so that $1-s\equiv 2t$ modulo $p$. (If $s$ is odd, then set $t=(1-s)/2\in\Bbb Z$, if $s$ is even, then use $p+s$ instead of $s$, which is odd and moves to the other case.) Then:
$$
|z|^2=z\cdot \bar z=\zeta^{2t}\cdot z^2=(\zeta^t\cdot z)^2\ ,
$$
so $|z|=\pm \zeta^t\cdot z\in\Bbb Q(\zeta)$.

---

*Note:* Not needed, but to be more convincing, let us show explicitly that $\zeta^t\cdot z$ is real. Its conjugate is equal to itself:
$$
\overline{\zeta^t\cdot z}=\zeta^{-t}\cdot\bar z=\zeta^{-t}\cdot\zeta^{2t}\cdot z=\zeta^t\cdot z
\ .
$$

---

A further *note* for the downvoters. The problem wants the following from us. Fix some primitive root $\zeta$ of unity of **odd order** $N$. (We do not need a prime.)
We consider the special $z$, let $z$ be the number from $K=\Bbb Q(\zeta)$:
$$
z = \frac{1-\zeta^6}{1-\zeta}=1+\zeta+\zeta^2+\zeta^3+\zeta^4+\zeta^5\ .
$$
The conjugate value is:
$$
\bar z = \frac{1-\zeta^{-5}}{1-\zeta}=1+\zeta^{-1}+\zeta^{-2}+\zeta^{-3}+\zeta^{-4}+\zeta^{-5}\ .
$$
The question is now if $|z|= \sqrt{z\bar z}$ is an element of the number field $K$. Yes, $z\bar z$ is an element of $K$, because $z,\bar z$ are in $K$. But now we **take the square root**, this may live $K$! In our case we rewrite $\bar z$ as
$$
\bar z = 
1+\zeta^{-1}+\zeta^{-2}+\zeta^{-3}+\zeta^{-4}+\zeta^{-5}
\\
=\zeta^{-5}(1+\zeta+\zeta^2+\zeta^3+\zeta^4+\zeta^5)\ .
$$
Now we have a quick chance to see $|z|^2 =z\cdot \bar z$ as a **square** element of $K$:
$$
|z|^2=z\cdot \bar z =z\cdot \zeta^{-5}z =\zeta^{-5}\cdot z^2=\zeta^{N-5}\cdot z^2\ ,
$$
and $N$ is **odd**, we need this fact, so that $\zeta^{N-4}$ is zeta to an even power. Finally we can take the square from the R.H.S. - which is $\pm \zeta^{(N-5)/2}\cdot z$, an element of the field $K$.

This later note is a pedestrian way to proceed, the first given argument is the same as this one.

Comment: The downvoter may maybe please explain... The above shows explicitly that the value $|z|$ is equal to an element that belongs to the field $\Bbb Q(\zeta)$. Where is the problem?

Comment: There is now one more downvoter, can i please get the reason for this action? Is there any error above? Is there an other simpler solution?! If yes, then please show it here, just expose it to the community!